# How do I synchronize the scroll position of two divs using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scroll

I have seen and used jQuery for synchronized scrolling, but for my current project am forced to find an Angular solution wherever possible. Unfortunately, I am not having any luck finding the "Angular way" for this problem.

Put simply, I need my top div (table header) to scroll horizontally in sync with my bottom div (table body). The two divs are children of a wrapper div. The first child is the slave, the second is the master, but I'm not sure what goes into the function to link the slave position to the master position...

```
.directive('scroll', [function() {
return {
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    ch = elem.children();
    slave = ch[0]; 
    master= ch[1];

    slave.bind('scroll', function(event){
      ...
    });
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4307/) is my example. It was initially written to combine vertical scrolls for two elements with the same size which are positioned in different blocks on page. I've rewritten it for horizontal scroll.

But it needs elements to be the same width. And it synchronizes the scroll - they are both master and slave at one time. If your elements have different sizes, you can set scroll using a proportion, something like `el.scrollLeft = scrollLeft*(el.width/otherEl.width)`.

Comment: Thanks! I dropped some lorem ipsum into the content divs, and switched the top overflow to hidden, to see the scrolling in action. It appears to do what I need. I do notice a tiny bit of lag when I apply this to my tables, which I did not see in the fiddle. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: It did not work in FF because isSameNode functionality has been removed. isEqualNode is the correct fn to go: http://jsfiddle.net/0w6n736q/

Answer (score 0):

My example (needs https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel):

```
myApp.directive("scrollGroup", function () {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("mousewheel", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $("[scroll-group='" + attrs.scrollGroup + "']").each(function () {
                $(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop() - e.deltaY);
                $(this).scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft() + e.deltaX);
            });
        });        
    };
});
```

You can then do something like:

```
<div class='div1' scroll-group='scroll_grp1'></div>
<div class='div2' scroll-group='scroll_grp1'></div>
<div class='div3' scroll-group='scroll_grp1'></div>
...
```

Does even work, when css `overflow: hidden` is set for the divs. That was important, because I did not want to see scrollbars in all the divs.

Tested in Firefox and Chrome and Safari 8.